# Development of Blood Pressure Monitor App for Wear OS(Samsung Galaxy Watch 4)

Tags: android, wear-os, wearables, samsung-galaxy-watch-4

I am interested in developing a **Blood Pressure Monitor** app(Android only) for **Samsung Galaxy Watch 4**(Wear OS). I have searched the internet but couldn't find any documentation or API that does that. I know it's not possible to measure the blood pressure without calibrating the watch first with a BP Monitor.

Is it possible to use Samsung's Health SDK?

I could only find this **[link](https://img-developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/health/android/data/com/samsung/android/sdk/healthdata/HealthConstants.BloodPressure.html)** which might help me.

Comment: pobably won't find a yes or no answer here, but from what i can see https://img-developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/health/android/data/index.html they do have _something_ related to this, have you tried downloading the sdk to see what it offers ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody yes, it seems like i can only get measured values using their SDK but i cannot measure the blood pressure in real time just like their watch does.

Comment: I wonder why they have made this so complicated. This should have been a very simple thing. I used a chinese watch SDK to measure everything very simply..

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to [What are country based features on Phone, controlled by?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/248890/3573) where the original poster (OP) was wondering why certain health related features were region locked.

Similarly for blood pressure,

From the Samsung Health app page: https://www.samsung.com/ca/apps/samsung-health-monitor/ and switching to the Blood Pressure tab at the bottom is the fine print

copied from the linked Samsung page on 2024-02-02:

> A Samsung Galaxy Watch* and smartphone (Android P OS version or higher) are required to use Samsung Health Monitor app. Due to country/region restrictions in obtaining approval/registration as a medical device, Samsung Health Monitor app only works on watches and smartphones purchased in the country/region where the service is currently available. However, service may be restricted/unavailable when users do a factory reset of the phone or delete and re-install the Samsung Health Monitor app while traveling in non-service country/region.
>
> - Blood Pressure App is available in the following country/region** (last updated on January 12 2024)
> - (1) Available on Galaxy Active 2, Galaxy Watch3, Galaxy Watch4 and later released models (excl. Galaxy Fit)
>   Argentina, Australia, Austria, Azerbaijan, Belgium, Bolivia, Brazil, Bulgaria, Canada, Chile, Christmas Island, Cocos (Keeling) Islands, Costa Rica, Croatia, Cyprus, Czechia, Denmark, Dominican Republic, Ecuador, El Salvador, Estonia, Finland, France, Georgia, Germany, Greece, Guatemala, Hong Kong, Honduras, Hungary, Iceland, Indonesia, Israel, Ireland, Italy, Korea, Latvia, Lithuania, Mayotte, Netherlands, Nicaragua, Norfolk Island, Norway, Panama, Paraguay, Peru, Poland, Portugal, Réunion, Romania, Russia, Singapore, Slovakia, Slovenia, South Africa, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, Taiwan, Türkiye, UK, Ukraine, UAE, Venezuela, and Vietnam
> - (2) Available only on Galaxy Watch4 and later released models (excl. Galaxy Fit)
>   China Mainland, India, Macau, Luxemburg, Malaysia, Malta, Mexico, New Zealand, Philippines, and Thailand
>
> **Service unavailable in other/overseas territories or regions unless specified under the country/region list.
>
> - Samsung Health Monitor Blood Pressure app is a 'medical device' in country/region where registration/approval is required and obtained. Note that availability of the Blood Pressure app may vary by country/region.
> - Please use after reading 'Precautions before use' and 'How to use' steps 1-4.
>
> Samsung Health Monitor Blood Pressure app is not intended for any diagnostic purposes regarding hypertension or other heart conditions, or for users under 22 years old. Users should not interpret results, or take clinical action based on the device output without consultation with a qualified healthcare professional. The Blood Pressure app is not intended to replace traditional methods of diagnosis or treatment.

Realize that Samsung calls out

**Samsung Health Monitor Blood Pressure app is a 'medical device' in country/region where registration/approval is required and obtained. Note that availability of the Blood Pressure app may vary by country/region.**

So by implication any blood pressure API that Samsung could provide, Samsung and any downstream app would have to follow the health device regulations of the region it is operating in. And the rules for each locality may vary. For example, perhaps real-time monitoring is considered sensitive health device data while aggregated data over some period may be allowed, region depending. So even with the disclaimer at the bottom regarding clinical usage, Samsung's own app health app is restricted.

Any no-name Chinese smartwatch with various health features may not be legally sold in your region with such features due to local regulations. Samsung is a global brand which will follow local regulations on health related devices and get approval.